# PHP file management application

Tags: php, bash, ssh, file-sharing

I am researching how to go about creating a web fronted file management application with a difference, and I'm a little stumped on one of the requirements I have.

I want my server to control file movement on remote servers but am not impressed with the speed of transfer I get out of samba/nfs mounts. For instance If I wanted to move a file from remote to remote mounted filesystem, there are 2 transfers that take place, 1 to the server then 1 to the remote destination. The size of the files I will be working with make this extremely inefficient.

The only way I can think of getting around this is to have my server ssh into the remote source and issue something like an rsync/scp to the remote desination.

**So I have 2 questions**

1) Is this my best/only action I can take?

2) Am I better using a PHP library to directly SSH or would I be better off passing the action onto something like a bash script? (or any others, any suggestions are welcome!)

Thanks for any info

Stewart

Comment: Is there any possibility of running web services on the remote servers?

Comment: Yes, this is entirely possible as my system design is still preliminary.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Address replies to commenters by using @ as in @Andrew so they're automatically notified.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to initiate direct transfers from server to server, without storing complete files in memory? You can use shell pipes for that. If you want to bypass the server completely, you should my use bittorrent protocol.